# Is there a way to "revive" a dead tuple in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, mvcc

Since `DELETE` does not physically removes the data and just marks it for further cleaning, i wonder, can the 'dead' status in a tuple version inside the file page ever be changed for 'redirect' or 'unused'? Will it happen after insertion of a new tuple version? As far as i'm concerned, 'redirect' status is assigned to a tuple after in-page cleaning for maintainig HOT-updated chains of pointers, so basically, can a dead tuple be not dead again?

Comment: There is the `pg_surgery` extension to freeze a tuple if you know its `ctid`, but I am not sure what you mean by "redirect" or "unused". Can you either describe your problem or use PostgreSQL technical terms to describe what you want?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Those are states described in pg source code, here is their description: https://doxygen.postgresql.org/itemid_8h_source.html
basically it's just numbers for describing a tuple state, you can find them inside a heap page using pageinspect extension

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you are talking about the `lp_flags` in an item pointer, defined in [`src/include/storage/itemid.h`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/include/storage/itemid.h) as `LP_UNUSED`, `LP_NORMAL`, `LP_REDIRECT` and `LP_DEAD`.

A line pointer that is marked `LP_DEAD` has to be reclaimed (set to `LP_UNUSED`) by `VACUUM`, then it is no longer referenced by any index and can be reused.